# Renaming in IAR Embedded Work Bench

Tags: iar

Is it possible to rename workspaces or projects? I am using 6.5_2 (although I have full versions of previous releases 4.0, 6.0)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To rename a workspace, but keep the projects in it all the same name as before, just simply rename the .eww file.

Since IAREWB doesn't actually provide the functionality to specifically rename a project, a work-around is required. What I do when trying to rename a workspace and it's associated project, I do this...

1. Copy Template.ewp (the project file) and rename the copy to say NewProject.ewp
2. Open Template.eww
3. Select Project->Add Existing Project...
4. Select NewProject.ewp and press Open
5. Select the "Template" tab at the bottom of the Workspace view
6. Right-click the project and select Remove
7. Close IAREWB, it will ask you to save the workspace, do that.
8. Rename the .eww, ewd to NewProject.eww, NewProject.ewd (and .dep if you have it)
9. Delete Template.ewp

You should then be able to open NewProject.eww as a completely renamed workspace and project.

If you want to only rename a project and keep the workspace the same name, only do steps 1-7

Hope that helps. and Good luck!

Comment: You can can rename the project directory before starting if you want the project folder name to match the new project name.

Comment: In step 6, user should change to "Overview" tab at first, then do the Right-click.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late to the party on this answer but I have had success renaming the .dep .ewd .ewp .ewt and .eww project files to the new project name and then using your text editor of choice to modify the .eww to point to the renamed .ewp (example below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspace>
    <project>
        <path>$WS_DIR$\my_new_project.ewp</path>
    </project>
    <batchBuild />
</workspace>
```

The advantage here being that if the project is under version control you won't have the add/remove of the .ewp which is advantageous, particularly working with multiple branches.

Once the file names are updated and the .eww is edited I have been able to open the project with no workspace, compilation or build errors (all assuming it compiled/built to start with).

Comment: This should be the preferred answer. A very simple fix.